# Wrong ds4 controller mapping

Tags: input

currently I'm having a very weird problem with my ds4 controller, its bindings are just wrong, right stick binds to triggers, triggers binds to right stick and buttons are all switched. It does work on steam thanks to the steam input, but not on native apps, does anyone know what may be causing this? Is there some way to reset the drivers?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.